# Scroll up the web page when specific element if reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a snippet of code that when page is loaded, it scrolls automatically to the last element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <h1 id="begin">Begin</h1>
    ...
    <h1 id="end">End</h1>

    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('body').scrollTo('#end', {duration:5000});
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is when it reaches the *end* element it scrolls up to *begin* element and then continue the process until specific tag is met.

So here are two questions:

1. How to make the window scrolls up when *end* is reached?
2. How can I check whether specific element id is encountered and stop the loop?

Comment: In which scenario you are executing scrollTo() method like clicking any button.And you said "It reaches end element".What does it mean and how you meeting the end element by scrolling the page ?

Comment: I mean that it scrolls from the top of the page to the bottom. Once it completed I want to send it to another element. Is it possible?

Comment: It seems in some webpages if we scroll down completely at the end of that we have option called "Top" . If you click that it will scroll to top of the page .. am i right ?

Comment: Well I don't want to go to the "Top" element, rather I want to go to specific id.

Answer (score 1):

This function will work

```
    $('.go-top').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').animate({                   
        scrollTop:$("YourID").offset().top + 'px'
            }, 'slow');});
```

Answer (score 1):

For going to particular element having `someID`:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#someID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

And to scroll to top of page:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
```

To check if is element is visible after scrolling:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Comment: I need to scroll to someID only when myCurrentID is reached. Or put in other words, I want scroll down to ID1, then once stopped scrolling move to ID2, and so on until ID9 is reached. How can I do this?

Comment: @BranAlgue:Updated the answer. call `isScrolledIntoView($("#someID"))` on pagescroll every time. it will return true if element is visible after scrolling.